# Why am I getting an ever increasing value of power co-efficient (Cp) with the increase of TSR in Vertical axis wind turbine simulation?

Tags: ansys

I am trying to get the bell-shaped Cp vs TSR graph in my 2D simulation of the H-Darrieus vertical axis wind turbine (using a sliding mesh model). However, I am always getting an ever increase of Cp value with the increase of TSR value i.e. the more I increase the value of the angular velocity of the sliding mesh, the higher the moment coefficient gets. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the bell-shaped curve?

#I am trying to replicate the task of the paper I have attached
#I have attached my ANSYS file
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HtQMmDJHReaM3IKPTjSBT0Ru3BtQtxIn?usp=sharing

Comment: Your questions seems more like an engineering than a programming guestion. Try posting it [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) instead. I think you'll have more luck there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'll do that.